# Map inside Bundle in intent is null in onStartCommand in Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, bundle

I am trying to start Service by passing some data through following code:

```
Intent countDownTimerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CountDownTimerService.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong(CountDownTimerService.DURATION, ((Test) mcqDataSet).getDuration());

        countDownTimerIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        getContext().startService(countDownTimerIntent );
```

Now when I am trying to receive the bundle data from Intent than it shows that some data is there in bundle but its map is null

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        final long duration = bundle.getLong(DURATION, 0l);
```

Here is how bundle looks will debugging 
[image: the debug mMap values here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I found that return type in onStartCommand should be **START_REDELIVER_INTENT**. It is because many times the intent gets lost and undelivered. So this return type forces it to redeliver it as it needs to get the data. Code is a follows:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) 
        final long duration = bundle.getLong(DURATION, 0l);

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the below code for sending the intent with data.

```
    Intent countDownTimerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CountDownTimerService.class);
    countDownTimerIntent.putExtra(CountDownTimerService.DURATION, ((Test) mcqDataSet).getDuration());
    getContext().startService(countDownTimerIntent );
```

Comment: I tried this way also but it is still giving data as null

Comment: After a lot of struggle, I found that return type in onStartCommand should be START_REDELIVER_INTENT. It is because many times the intent gets lost and undelivered. @RaghavPai